# Sticky or fixed overlay to visible area of scrollable div- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, overlay

I've this code for a chat box that scrolls on adding messages in it.
I've to show an overlay on it  that should not scroll up with messages it should stay over messages if scroll the chat box it scrolls to bottom on addition of messages.

```
<style>
  #overlay {
   display: none;
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   z-index: 2;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;

}
 .chat-area {
  background-color:#f3f3f3;
  height: 75px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  position:relative
}
<style>

<div class="chat-area" id="chat-area">
    <div id="overlay">
        <div class="warning">Registro requerido para chatear
        <a href="http://trackstuff.net/path/out.php" target="_blank">Regístrate ahora</a></div>    
    </div><!-- overlay -->
    <div class='row chat-entered'>
        <div class='isTyping'><a href="http://trackstuff.net/path/out.php" class="is-typing-link">SexySlut22</a> está escribiendo......</div>
    </div>  
</div><!-- chat-area -->
```

On addition of new message in chatbox I'm using this line of js to make it scroll to latest message in the bottom.

```
let objDiv = document.getElementById("chat-area");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

**I've tried position fixed to  overlay** it makes  it disappear..
Pls let me know if there is a  solution in JS or CSS. Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```js
setInterval(function(){
  
  let messages = document.getElementById('messages');
  
  messages.innerHTML = messages.innerHTML + 
  '<div class="row chat-entered">' + 
    '<div class="isTyping"><a href="#" class="is-typing-link">Username</a>:' + Math.random() + '</div>' + 
   '</div>';
  
  let objDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
  
}, 400);
```

```css
#overlay {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   z-index: 2;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   color:white;
}
#overlay a {
  color:white; 
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.warning {
  position: absolute; 
  top:50%; left:0
  transform:translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
.chat-area {
  display: block;
  background-color:#f3f3f3;
  position: relative
}
#messages {
  overflow:hidden;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="chat-area" id="chat-area">
  <div id="overlay">
    <div class="warning">Registro requerido para chatear <a target="_blank">Regístrate ahora</a></div>    
  </div><!-- overlay -->
  <div id="messages">
    <div class='row chat-entered'>
      <div class='isTyping'><a href="#" class="is-typing-link">Username</a> está escribiendo......</div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- messages -->
</div><!-- chat-area -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @NadeemGorsi just change overflow to hidden